# How to find the value from this array in php?

Tags: php

i have an Array , How can get the value of this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => raj
            [1] => 1234
            [2] => gov
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => some
            [1] => 1234
            [2] => prv
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => lal
            [1] => 234
            [2] => prv
        )
)
```

i want the value like this type: raj, 1234, gov

Comment: What do you exactly want? Some strings like "raj, 1234, gov" for each high-level array elements?

Comment: What is your input? One of the subarrays? A string e.g. containing `'raj'`? You have to give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
     echo 'type: ' . $data[$i][0] . ', ' . $data[$i][1] . ', ' . $data[$i][2] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This is one way to output it, and the result should be:

```
type: raj, 1234, gov 
type: some, 1234, prv 
type: lal, 234, prv
```

Comment: All are correct, but i find a error in data[$i][0] and here is the answer for($i=0; $i<count(data); $i++){
     echo 'type: ' . data[$i][0] . ', ' . data[$i][1] . ', ' . data[$i][2] . PHP_EOL;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($aArray as $aValues) {
    echo "type: ".implode(", ", $aValues);
    echo "<br>"; // Or alternative linebreak.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

If your array above was stored in the variable `$foo`, getting the first nested array within is as easy as `$foo[0]` (second is `$foo[1]`. third is `$foo[2]`, and so on). Then, to get the values within that, you can reference the nested values within using the same method (the brackets).

```
$foo = /* that array */

$foo[0] // this is the first array, array([0] => 'raj', [1] => 1234, [2] => 'gov');

$foo[0][0] // this is "raj" (reference element one of the first array)

echo implode(', ',$foo[0])); // use implode and make all element of "$foo[0]"
                             // display, separated by commas and a space.
```

**[demo](http://www.ideone.com/rHq7H)**