# Getting values from a single array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the value from this array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126512/how-to-find-the-value-from-this-array-in-php)

hello coders.I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => admin/login
            [1] => LoginHandler
            [2] => index
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => post
            [1] => PostHandler
            [2] => index
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => post/create
            [1] => postHandler
            [2] => create
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => post/update
            [1] => postHandler
            [2] => update
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => post/delete
            [1] => postHandler
            [2] => delete
        )

)
```

I want only the values  like `admin/login, LoginHandler,index,`
`post,PostHandler,index`,
`post/create,PostHandler,create` and so on.So how to do that?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You can access any item with `$array[i]` where is `i` is the index of the corresponding element.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the array to perform an action on each element:

```
foreach ( $your_array as $element ) {
    if ( is_array( $element ) ) {
        foreach ( $element as $sub_element ) {
            // You can store this value in a variable, or output it in your desired format.
            echo $sub_element . "<br />";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $element . "<br />";
    }
}
```