# Getting Twitter followers with JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter, json

I can get Tweets of users quite easily using PHP and JSON, but as soon as I use it to get a list of followers, I get errors. Both use JSON to return the values.

The code is:

```
$jsonurl = "https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=mooinooicat";
$contents = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$results = json_decode($contents, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

This gives me the following array:

```
Array
(
    [next_cursor] => 0
    [ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31085924
            [1] => 53633023
            [2] => 18263583
        )

    [previous_cursor] => 0
    [next_cursor_str] => 0
    [previous_cursor_str] => 0
)
```

How do I get the values of next_cursor and previous_cursor and how do I loop just through the ids array?

I want to parse the results for reading into a database.

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @andrebruton https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json it provides us ids of followers of screen name which I provide, can we get screen names instead ?

Comment: See: [Twitter Followers API Tutorial](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids)

Answer (score 1):

you are not using the correct api try something like this

```
function fetch_twitter_count($user) {
    if ($json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=$user")) {
        if(empty($json)) return 0;

        $json = json_decode($json['body'], true);

        return number_format(intval($json['followers_count']));
    }
    return 'API Error';
}
```

have not tested but should do what you want however keep inmind that you will want to use some sort of caching

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers without examples...

I finally managed to figure it out using the example from [Getting values from a single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142608/getting-values-from-a-single-array)

Here is the code:

```
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
  if ( is_array( $result ) ) {
    foreach ( $result as $sub_result ) {
      // You can store this value in a variable, or output it in your desired format.
      echo $sub_result . "<br />";
    }
  } else {
    echo $result . "<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want the array key and the value, use: foreach ( $result as $key=>$value ) { and then the key name will be $key and the value will be $value